why Eureka don't see name of microservice
enter image description here
application.yml(client)
spring:
  application:
    name: user-service
server:
  port: 0
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true

application.yml(eureka)
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

i tried a lot of things

I found this configuration on Spring Getting Started Tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery) for Eureka service and client. It seems that there is no need to include the "service-url" property, as this is set by default by spring. I would recommend using something like this.
spring:
    application:
      name: eureka-server
server:
    port: 8761
eureka:
    client:
     register-with-eureka: false
     fetch-registry: false
logging:
    level:
     com.netflix.eureka: OFF
     com.netflix.discovery: OFF

As for the client, using the defaults everything should work out of the box.
Be careful to include the necessary @Enable annotations for Eureka!
